# Username live check using Ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code in which there's a function which is supposed to check if a username is available or not.

I'm confused about how this function works.

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#register-form").validationEngine();
});
```

**HTML input:**

```
<form action="" id="register-form">
    <input value="" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],ajax[ajaxNameCallPhp]]] input" type="text" name="username"/>
</form>
```

**This is my JS function:**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){};
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function(){
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {

                "ajaxNameCallPhp": {
                    // remote json service location
                    "url": "ajaxNameCallPhp.php",
                    // error
                    "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                    // speaks by itself
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                }
            };
        }
    };

    $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();
})(jQuery);
```

**and this is my `ajaxNameCallPhp.php` function:**

```
include ("config.php");
$username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$username = mysql_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num;
mysql_close();
```

So anyone can give me a solutions ?

I appreciate and thanks with your attention.

Thank you.

Comment: If I input something in textbox, It always show * Validating, please wait.

Comment: Please post the rest of your js.  That 'function' is quite clearly part of a larger object.

Comment: have you thought maybe it doesn't exist?

Comment: Refer [link](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/)

Comment: @all thanks for your comment, I have updated my post. Please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function UserNameExist(){ 
    $("#msg").html( "* Validating, please wait" );
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajaxNameCallPhp.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {username : $('#username').val()},
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(msg) {
      if(msg > 0){
        $("#msg").html( "* This name is available" );
      }else{
        $("#msg").html( "* This name is already taken" );
      }
    });
   }
```

where #msg is the id of the div where you show your massage

and #userName is the id of the text box

hope that help.